# Extract ZIP using PowerShell 2.0

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file

I am writing a script that needs to extract a ZIP file. The problem is that all the deployment machines are Windows 2008 R2 and have PowerShell 2.0 installed. I found the following code on another website that will supposedly work, however I need to do all of this from the command line rather than creating a PowerShell script.

How can I write the following code where I can call it using `powershell.exe -command (New-Object System.Net.ShellApplication)` for example?

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\howtogeeksite.zip")
foreach($item in $zip.Items()) {
    $shell.Namespace("C:\temp\howtogeek").CopyHere($item)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it directly to `-Command` by joining the lines with `;`, ex:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command $shell = new-object -com shell.application; $zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\howtogeeksite.zip”); foreach($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.Namespace(“C:\temp\howtogeek”).copyhere($item) }
```

or you could use a base64-encoded string.

```
powershell -?

..
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
    $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
    $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Ex generate command:

```
$command = @'
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("C:\howtogeeksite.zip")
foreach($item in $zip.Items()) {
    $shell.Namespace("C:\temp\howtogeek").CopyHere($item)
}
'@

[convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))

#output
JABzAGgAZQBsAGwAIAA9ACAAbgBlAHcALQBvAGIAagBlAGMAdAAgAC0AYwBvAG0AIABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBhAHAAcABsAGkAYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4ADQAKACQAegBpAHAAIAA9ACAAJABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBOAGEAbQBlAFMAcABhAGMAZQAoABwgQwA6AFwAaABvAHcAdABvAGcAZQBlAGsAcwBpAHQAZQAuAHoAaQBwAB0gKQANAAoAZgBvAHIAZQBhAGMAaAAoACQAaQB0AGUAbQAgAGkAbgAgACQAegBpAHAALgBpAHQAZQBtAHMAKAApACkADQAKAHsADQAKACQAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4ATgBhAG0AZQBzAHAAYQBjAGUAKAAcIEMAOgBcAHQAZQBtAHAAXABoAG8AdwB0AG8AZwBlAGUAawAdICkALgBjAG8AcAB5AGgAZQByAGUAKAAkAGkAdABlAG0AKQANAAoAfQA=
```

Using the encoded command:

```
powershell -NoProfile -encodedCommand JABzAGgAZQBsAGwAIAA9ACAAbgBlAHcALQBvAGIAagBlAGMAdAAgAC0AYwBvAG0AIABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBhAHAAcABsAGkAYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4ADQAKACQAegBpAHAAIAA9ACAAJABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBOAGEAbQBlAFMAcABhAGMAZQAoABwgQwA6AFwAaABvAHcAdABvAGcAZQBlAGsAcwBpAHQAZQAuAHoAaQBwAB0gKQANAAoAZgBvAHIAZQBhAGMAaAAoACQAaQB0AGUAbQAgAGkAbgAgACQAegBpAHAALgBpAHQAZQBtAHMAKAApACkADQAKAHsADQAKACQAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4ATgBhAG0AZQBzAHAAYQBjAGUAKAAcIEMAOgBcAHQAZQBtAHAAXABoAG8AdwB0AG8AZwBlAGUAawAdICkALgBjAG8AcAB5AGgAZQByAGUAKAAkAGkAdABlAG0AKQANAAoAfQA=
```

Answer (score 4):

I found it on Reddit so thought I would share the answer...

```
powershell.exe (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace("E:\foldername").CopyHere((new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace("E:\test.zip").Items())
```